# Symfony Panther : can't login with form

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-panther

I'm testing an application with Symfony Panther. I want to log in the user to have not provided elements in anonymous conditions. Here is my test class :

```
namespace App\Tests\Functional;

use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;

class SecurityControllerTest extends PantherTestCase
{
    public function testConnexion()
    {
        $client = static::createPantherClient('127.0.0.1', '9001');

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/connexion');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Se connecter')->form();
        $form['_email'] = 'email@domain.com';
        $form['_password'] = 'password';

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

//        $link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Déconnexion")')->link();
//        $crawler = $client->click($link);

        $link = $crawler->selectLink('Déconnexion');
        $link->click();
        $this->assertSame(self::$baseUri.'/', $client->getCurrentURL());
    }
}
```

The associated template (`connexion.html.twig`) :

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}

{% block page_title 'Login' %}

{% block final_javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('sendCredentials') }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

        (...)

            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form id="connexion-form" action="{{ path('security_connexion') }}" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="_email" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button">Se connecter</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the `_nav.html.twig` template which represents the navigation bar :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path("index") }}"><img src="{{ asset("images/temporary-logo.png") }}" alt="shinigami-laser-logo" style="max-height: 60px;"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        (...)

            {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}


                {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('logged_infos') }}" class="nav-link  shogun-link">Mes infos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  shogun-link">Gerer mes cartes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  shogun-link">Mes stats</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link  shogun-link" href="{{ path('security_deconnexion') }}">Déconnexion</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link  shogun-link" href="{{ path('user_enregistrement') }}">S'enregistrer</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link  shogun-link" href="{{ path('security_connexion') }}">Se connecter</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In dev mode the user can authenticate and log out with the `Déconnexion` link in the navbar.
But the command `php bin/phpunit tests/Functional/SecurityControllerTest.php` says : `InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.` pointing on this line : `$link->click();` revealing that the `Déconnexion` link is not visible.
Is that user is not logged in ?
How to fix that and access provided elements for authanticated user like the `Déconnexion` link ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods:

```
$crawler->selectButton('.btn-primary');
$crawler->executeScript("document.querySelector('.btn-primary').click()");
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#forms

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please `edit` to use proper code formatting. See sidebar for how to do this, or highlight the code and use the edit toolbar. Also, code only dumps are discouraged on SO. Consider adding an explanation of how/why your suggestion solves the OP's issue. Upvotes are achieved over time on quality answers when future visitors learn something to apply to their own coding issues or when a post increases their knowledge generally. Including links to documentation can also be helpful.  You can read more on SO guidelines at StackOverflow.com/help. We look forward to more of your insights.